# how do I preserve method annotations in JMockit mocked instance

Tags: java, jmockit

I tried to mock class with method annotations via JMockit,  and discovered that no method annotations were retrievable via reflection. Field annotations work as intendet. Do I miss something?

Mocking:

```
    @Test
public void testThatSetterInjectionIsBombedProperlyOnNonAssignability(@Mocked final WithInjectableMethods injectable,
                                                                      @Mocked final TextView textView,
                                                                      @Mocked final Button button) {
```

Class in question:

```
class WithInjectableMethods extends Activity {

    private android.view.View asView;

    private Button button;

    // shall be left alone
    private View notInjected = null;
    // shall be injected


    @InjectView(id = 239)
    private void setAsView(View asView) {
        this.asView = asView;
    }

    @InjectView(id = 555)
    public void setButton(Button button) {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void setNotInjected(View notInjected) {
        this.notInjected = notInjected;
    }
```

Comment: Issue closed.   I was able to work around by excluding methods  in question from mocking (see issue comments) :  And issue is being fixed  in the next release: http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/issues/detail?id=184

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work around:

```
   @Mocked(methods = {"setAsView", "setButton", "notInjected"}, inverse = true) final WithInjectableMethods injectable,
```

I also started issue on jmockit, it was acepted and fix is promissed in the next release:

http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/issues/detail?id=184